# Can one define a keyboard shortcut to perform command on file selected in nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

Say you're looking at files in nautilus. Is there some way to define a keyboard shortcut to execute command on the currently marked file?

For example, when I want to share photos, I'm often browsing through a ton of pictures in Nautilus, trying to find the ones to share. Having a keyboard shortcut set to "Copy currently selected to .. folder" would be very handy.

Comment: See this blog - http://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2010/08/29/extending-nautilus-context-menus-using-nautilus-actions-scripts-and-python-extensions/

Comment: I'm afraid adding an item to the context menu alone is not the solution I'm looking for, but thank you. Unless I can make a shortcut key to those... Hm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scripts to do that. Look here http://g-scripts.sourceforge.net/

These can be incorporated into Nautilus for right click operation. Sharing options, copy and move per se.